# I am not able to click on Google Search Button

Tags: automated-testing, browser-automation

This is the HTML source of the button:

```
<input value="Google Search" aria-label="Google Search" name="btnK" type="submit">
```

This is my code:

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
//import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class google {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C://chromedriver_win32//chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");
            //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='TZA4S']/div[1]/div[1]/input")).sendKeys("Kedarnath review");

            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='tsf']/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input")).sendKeys("kedarnath collection");
            //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//@id=(//*[@id='tsf']/div[2]/div[3]/input)")).click();

            //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//@id=(//*[@id='tsf']/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]//center/input[1]")).click();


            /*Issue in below line able to click on Search Button*/
            driver.findElement(By.name("btnK")).click();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//div[@class='FPdoLc VlcLAe']//input[@type='submit' and @value= 'Google Search']
```

There are 2 matching nodes available. The only difference is the class name. So construct your xpath with the class name

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

Solution 1: 
**//div[@class='FPdoLc VlcLAe']//input[@name='btnK']**

Explanation: If you are going to use **//*[@name='btnK']** or  driver.findElement(By.name("btnK")).click(); then there are 2 matching nodes.

[image]

Solution 2:
In case you want to go with locator **name** - then try below solution

**(//*[@name='btnK'])[ 2]** (write 2 in bracket without spaces)

[image]

Comment: Please edit your answer to explain why your suggestion will work and why the OP's find by name failed. That will make your answer more relevant to other situations where someone is having problems with locators

Answer (score 0):

Use,

```
driver.findElement(By.name("btnK"))[2].click();
```

Since the name btnK has two matches, so use this above line.

Comment: the above solution is not working and found below exception

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to WebElement

 at google.main(google.java:25)

Comment: It should be `findElements` I think, and in that case if it is an array that will be returned, using index `2` will return the third button if there is or an ArrayOutOfBound exception will be thrown. Also I would not recommend to find  an element using such index as if the page changes, a new button is introduced your test will be broken.

Comment: for findElements
the IDE itself showing “The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to List <WebElements>”

Answer (score 0):

The below XPath will enable the scripts to click on "Google Search" button:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='FPdoLc VlcLAe']/center/input[1]")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The "Google Search" button `XPath: //div[@class="FPdoLc VlcLAe"]//input[1];`
2. The "I'm Feeling Lucky" button `XPath: //div[@class="FPdoLc VlcLAe"]//input[2]`.